# Is the Brownian motion multiplication rule a definition or is it a theorem?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Is the Brownian motion multiplication rule a definition or is it a theorem?

Refer to the highlight part of https://i.stack.imgur.com/doQuT.png where $dw_1(t)dw_1(t)=dt$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a lemma! Ito's Lemma gives the change of coordinates rule for stochastic calculus. The multiplication rule is a shorthand way of expressing it.

Comment: Why is it known as a lemma? If you go through the original paper from 1944, you will note that is actually a theorem.

Comment: I don't know what it's named as a lemma, but everybody believes it's a definition.

Comment: most books call it "Ito's Lemma"!

Comment: Then I would argue that most books are mistaken, since it is a theorem in the original paper. Not that it really matter though.

Comment: @Olorun: There is no technical difference, only an organizational one. An axiom is a logical sentence with truth value set to *true*, with no questions asked. A logical framework is a collection of axioms + a collection of derivation rules (rules that tell you how new ture sentences are produced from other true ones). A theorem is a logical sentence that is derivable within a particular logical framework. Now a corollary is what you call a theorem if it follows immediately from other theorems. And a lemma is what you call a theorem when it's just an intermediate result towards another theorem.

Comment: Also, given it's status, "lemma" is a misnomer for Ito's lemma. Other examples for very important theorems that historically were called lemma are, for example, the [Yoneda lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma), [Zorn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma) or [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma).

Answer (score 5):

Formally, this is a shorthand for the quadratic variation. 
For a more rudimentary definition, $\langle W, W\rangle$ is a process such that $W^2-\langle W, W\rangle$ is a martingale. Moreover, $\langle W, W\rangle_t$ is a limit, in probability, of the variation
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n|W_{t_{i}}-W_{t_{i-1}}|^2,
\end{align*}
over the partition
\begin{align*}
0=t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_n = t.
\end{align*}
From the property of a standard Brownian motion, it can be shown that the above limit equals $t$. That is, $\langle W, W\rangle_t = t$.

In general, if $X_t = \int_0^t \xi_s dW_s$ and $Y_t = \int_0^t \eta_s dW_s$, then
\begin{align*}
\langle X, Y \rangle_t &= \int_0^t \xi_s \eta_s ds,
\end{align*}
which we also write as
\begin{align*}
\langle dX_t, dY_t\rangle = \xi_t\eta_tdt.
\end{align*}
For $\xi_t=\eta_t = 1$, we then have
\begin{align*}
\langle dW_t, dW_t\rangle = dt,
\end{align*}
which is usually write as $dW_t dW_t = dt$.

Comment: Can I add that it means the Brownian motion accumulates t units of quadratic variation.

Comment: @StudentT:  That is correct.